# Android iframe player controls

Tags: android, html, android-studio, iframe, android-webview

I want to play embedded videos (not youtube videos) in my android app. I know how to use iframe but i dont get options fo seek to skip. Is there any library for that to play iframe videos easily in android app?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
webviewWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_web_view);

webviewWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webviewWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webviewWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

String customHtml = "<iframe width=\"380\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLBRur06WH1SlYw3rIr051vPw442oBB50e\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
webviewWebView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```